# Use of [before] or [in front of] in an expression about submission or yielding

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I want to express that a crew wanted a captian to resign. The captain didn't want to resign but the crew's wishes prevailed over the Captain's.

Is it idiomatic to word the idea like:

> Soon the captain resigned **before** the crew's wishes.

or

> Soon the captain resigned **in front of** the crew's wishes.

?

If not, what word would work there?

Comment: *in front of* tends to be more literal; *before* can mean "in the presence of", so it is more applicable.

Comment: Neither sounds right to me. Can we have more context? What was happening before this and afterwards.

Comment: @stangdon— I mean to say _the crew's strong will prevailed over the Captain's wishes._ Is _in front of_ idiomatic? I'm kinda meaning to say _against._

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you mean to say. As you explained in the comment. It will also help give a better answer if you can explain why you have the question. For example, if you’re writing something, the best answer may be something like *The crew pressured him/her so hard that he soon resigned.* But that depends on the context.

Comment: I doubt any captain would resign due to the "crew's wishes".

Comment: @Jim Reynolds I just needed to know if _before/in front of_ is idiomatic. My bad, couldn't think of a better example sentence. I agree with you Lambie that it's an illogical situation. But like I said I'm solely concerned with the idiomaticness of _before/in front of._

Comment: Idiomatic in what context(s)? Please tell us what you have found in dictionaries, then ask any questions you may still have, tell us what you want one or both of them to mean, then give some possible examples and ask if they're idiomatic (if you can't figure it out by searching online for examples). As it stands now, unfortunately, it looks to me like this should be closed after all.

Comment: @Jim Reynolds What i mean by idiomatic here is that is it okay to use _before/in front of_ when making comparisons, presenting opposite stances like in the example sentence given. A similar sentence: _He was nothing *before/in front of* his friend (I'm trying to compare the two here). In the "captain example" I meant to contrast the two likewise. That's what I meant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @stangdon mentioned in a comment *before* is a more general term than *in front of* which tends to be used in more literal senses like *in front of a building*. However if I was saying this I would say

> He resigned in the face of the crew's wishes
> He resigned in the light of the crew's wishes

As pointed out in a comment

> He resigned in light of the crew's wishes

also works and some people may prefer it. He also questioned whether *in the face of* had the same nuance the OP was searching for but it still seems appropriate to me.